# What is the translation for "random" in German?

Tags: word-usage, single-word-request

What is the correct translation for saying something like "wow that was random." Random as in weird, not as in having a lack of pattern.

Comment: As the answer point out there are a lot of translations. I think a concrete context could narrow down the range of possible answers. As the question is now, I would tend to "komisch", since it is an often used word to describe weird and strange things.

Comment: When you're with young people you could probably just say "Das war random" and anyone would understand. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Von den Vorschlägen, die [dict.leo liefert](http://dict.leo.org/ende?search=weird), erscheinen mir mit zufällig kombiniert am ehesten:

- merkwürdig
- eigenartig
- seltsam
- sonderbar
- komisch
- ulkig
- unheimlich
- gruselig   auch: gruslig
- bizarr
- übernatürlich

also fast alle, allerdings die ersten eher als die letzten bzw. die letzten in Abhängigkeit vom Kontext. Wenn jmd. zum dritten Mal vom Blitz getroffen wird, wird man es eher gruselig als komisch bezeichnen, ein Huhn mit drei Köpfen findet man dagegen vielleicht eher komisch/ulkig als übernatürlich.

Insbesondere in Kombination mit *unwahrscheinlich* kann man die meisten der Adjektive kombinieren, um die Bedeutung zu unterstreichen, ohne dass die *Wahrscheinlichkeitsüberlegung,* die eigentlich offensichtlich im Wort steckt, noch sonderlich bewusst würde; so sehr ist es eine stehende Redewendung.

Answer (score 15):

To match the English (as I understand it) as closely as possible (including the "tone") I'd suggest forgetting any literal attempt...

I would expect to hear "Wow, that was random" from someone rather young (under 40 maybe?) who just saw or heard something odd, but also if he experienced some unusual social behaviour (e.g. someone jostled him and then behaved as though it was his fault or something)

The closest you can get would probably be one of two versions with slightly different overtones:

> "**Das war abgefahren**", or "**Wow - abgefahren**" <sup>brought to you by nem75 - thanks!</sup> - this often implies that the occurence was weird in a good way
>
> "**Was war das denn jetzt?**" - this can express amusement and annoyance ...usually said with a raised eyebrow. :)

Comment: +1 Yes, that one seems to hit the right "tone".

Comment: What about *krass*? Seems to me to strike a chord similar to *abgefahren*. Depending on the context, I might prefer one or the other.

Answer (score 6):

You could use word "komisch" which has couple of meanings and weird is one of them. The other word that might work is "wahllos"(something done indiscriminately). In German "wahllos" has this negative connotation and also includes the "weird" part. However, "komisch" is a better word I think because "wahllos" is too negative and straightforward.

Comment: +1 for komisch. I definitely would not use "wahllos" as an translation in this context, because it really *only* means "without any pattern" and does not convey the sense of "dude, wtf?" as "random" does.

Comment: "Willkürlich" could apply in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

There simply is no general equivalent in German. Depending on the context you could say:  **Donnerwetter, das kam jetzt aber unerwartet!** (wow that came/was unexpected.)

Answer (score 1):

My proposal for the sentence would be "Was für ein Zufall!" (possible paraphrase: what a strange conicidence). It uses the German noun for "random", but in this colloquial context nobody would attach the technical meaning.

Comment: I guess I'm nobody. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The words I would use are "seltsam" and "unheimlich." These words have the connotations of "not normal."

Comment: I'd say they "unheimlich" also has a strong connotation of "creepy" rather than "weird" - if I understand "random" correctly in this context, it's more an expression of amusement, isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

Ich übersetze das immer mit *zufällig*, im wörtlichen Sinne. Im Sinne von: eine Zufallszahl (random number) ziehen oder ein "Zufallslied" beim Random-Programm der Musikanlage.

Comment: Actually this does not answer the question. (_Random as in weird, not as in having a lack of pattern._)